Understanding the singularity at the origin of the Riemann surface associated to $\sqrt[n]{}$
Let $U_0=\mathbb{C}\backslash[-\infty,0]$; it is a simply connected planar open Riemann surface. Le $n\geq 2$ be a fixed integer and consider the function $z\mapsto\sqrt[n]{z}$ which is holomorphic and single valued on $U_0$. Now following Riemann's idea, we wish to extend holomorphically this function as we move along paths that circle the origin, and in order to this one needs to "extend" $U_0$ to a larger surface. Doing this in a  "minimal way", one can construct the so-called Riemann surface associate to $\sqrt[n]{z}$ which we denote by $\mathbb{S}_n$. Here minimal can be understood categorically as a strict terminal object in the category of all commutative diagrams which look like this:
$\hspace{5cm}$
Here $Y$ is a connected Riemann surface, $f=\sqrt[n]{z}$,; $\widetilde{f}$ is a (single-valued) holomorphic extension of $f$ to $Y$ (necessarily unique from the connectedness of $Y$) and $\pi$ is locally a biholomorphism which maps $V_0$ biholomorphically to $U_0$.
Now, recall that $\mathbb{S}_n$ can be constructed in the following way: Let $U=U_0\cup L^+\cup L^{-}$ where $L^+=[-\infty,0]$ is the upper edge of the slit and $L^{-}=[-\infty,0]$ is the lower edge of the slit. So $U$ is a $2$-dimensional topological surface with a boundary which contains the open set $U_0$ (it is clearly homeomorphic to the closed upper half-plane). Concretely one may construct $\mathbb{S}_n$ by gluing $n$-copies of $U$ in a cyclic manner: if $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ are  $n$ copies then we identify $L_i^{+}$ with $L_{i+1}^{-}$ for $1\leq i\leq n-1$ and we identify $L_{n}^{+}$ with $L_1^{-}$. In this way we obtain a $2$-dimensional surface $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n$ which is singular at the origin $0$. Now it is not possible to set $Y=\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n$ in the above diagram since the map $\pi$ would fail to be a biholomorphism in a neighboorhood of $0\in \widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n$ (this uses the fact that $n\geq 2$) and in fact we must have $\mathbb{S}_n:=\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n\backslash\{0\}$. It is straightforward to see that $\mathbb{S}_n$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ (an open cylinder). In particular, $\mathbb{S}_n$ does not recall the value $n$.
Here is an immersion of $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$\hspace{6cm}$
Note that the true $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_2$ has no self-intersection. It seems to me that the singular surfaces $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n$ are not homeomorphic for distinct values of $n$. In some sense, at the origin $0$, there are kind of $n$-sheets passing through $0$, but it is not clear to me how to formalize this using classical tools from algebraic topology. For example, if one places an observer at the singular point, is it possible for this observer to detect that there are $n$-sheets that meet the origin and which are organized in a cyclic way ?
So here is my math question:
Q: What are the formal ways of characterizing (i.e. understanding) the singularity $0$ of the singular surface  $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_n$ ?

An observer at the origin can put a finger on the origin, put a mark on the floor, then walk in a (generalized) circle until arriving back at the mark.  Now compute measured circumference divided by $2\pi$ times measured radius to get the number of sheets of the covering.  I don't see an easy way (restricted to an infinitesimal neighborhood of the origin) to distinguish cyclic from more complicated covers.

Have you considered using a logarithmic transformation to make the sheets be infinitely wide tiles of height $2 \pi \mathrm{i}$, pushing the "singularity" away to $-\infty$?  (This can be framed as a projectivization or as a blow up.)

@Eric, is it possible to define a smooth metric in a neighbourhood of the origin ?

Since you are expressing your question in complex analytic language, let me give start with a complex analysis answer (which leads to an algebraic topology answer, as I'll show).
As you say, $\mathbb S_n$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C^\times$.
But you should be careful about using the terminology "singular surface" for $\widehat{\mathbb S}_n$ itself. The point here is that $U_i - \{0\}$ for $1 \le i \le n$ can equally well be taken as the angular sector $2\pi (i-1)/n \le \theta \le 2 \pi i/n$ with the origin missing: just apply a branch of the function $\sqrt[n]{z}$ to your $U$ thingy. So when the $U_i - \{0\}$'s are pieced together, you get an explicit biholomorphism between $\mathbb S_n \approx \mathbb C - \{0\}$. The "missing point" $0$ is a removable singularity, and filling in that removable singularities is indistinguishable from filling in the missing point $0$. That is to say, $\widehat{\mathbb S}_n$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C$.
It follows that $\widehat{\mathbb S}_n$ is independent of $n$ from a complex analytic point of view. But then it follows furthermore that it is also independent of $n$ from a topological point of view: each $\widehat{\mathbb S}_n$ is homeomorphic to the plane.

I see, in fact, your second paragraph where you explain the gluing in a cyclic manner of the singular sectors was my way of proving that $\mathbb{S}_n$ was biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$. I'm potentially ready to buy your explanation but I'm still confused about one thing. If you look at the immersion for example of $\widehat{\mathbb{S}}_2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$, it does not seem to me that the origin  admits a neighboorhood homeomorphic to a disc ?

That's not too surprising, and not a contradiction, because immersions that are not one-to-one are also not homeomorphisms.

I regard that picture as a helpful visualization tool, but be careful not to over-interpret it.

Ok I buy it! I give now more credence to your formal proof than the picture. I'm very glad to have posted that question since for some reason I had fooled myself that there was a singularity at the origin Thanks a lot @Lee for straightening the twisted picture at the origin and incidentally my own thinking!
